# jQuery UI Autocomplete value not appear properly in selection

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, laravel-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My sources are JSON objects that fetched from url and it looks like below.

```
[
    {"ID":1,"GROUP_ID":"1","CONTACTNAME":"Mizuki","PHONENUMBER":"+6289695049930"},
    {"ID":15,"GROUP_ID":"3","CONTACTNAME":"Sinbad","PHONENUMBER":"+6287654321"},
    {"ID":23,"GROUP_ID":"","CONTACTNAME":"Titus","PHONENUMBER":"+6255555555"}
];
```

When user typing, result of suggestion is CONTACTNAME and value that inserted into searchbox is PHONENUMBER. Fetch data from source/url have no issue but in searchbox there's no value passed.

Screenshot below
[image: empty value]

Here's my script

```
$(function() {
    $( "#contact" ).autocomplete({
        source: "api/contact/auto",
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#contact").val(ui.item.CONTACTNAME);
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#contact").val(ui.item.PHONENUMBER);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Form view

```
<input type="text" v-model="message.DESTINATIONNUMBER" id="tags" class="form-control" name="destinationNumber" >
```

I try to remove vue snippet (v-model) still same.

Any suggestion? Whats wrong?

**UPDATED!!**
My mistake. Forgot add this code at the end.

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

So, full javascript is like in jquery-ui docs

```
$(function() {
    $( "#contact" ).autocomplete({
        source: "api/contact/auto",
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#contact").val(ui.item.CONTACTNAME);
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#contact").val(ui.item.PHONENUMBER);
            return false;
        }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

Thanks for people who try to help me. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please create a https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @NoyGabay uh sorry, i will try it. Because my app built using laravel.

Comment: @NoyGabay try here https://jsfiddle.net/ep1s9w3s/ its not work at all, am newbie at jsfiddle :(

Answer (score 0):

For the autocomplete to work, you need to have "label" attribute in the returned JSON array. You can either change that on the server side, or transform it on the client as follows:

```
$( "#contact" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/contact/auto",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.CONTACTNAME,
                        value: el.PHONENUMBER,
                        id: el.ID
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    });
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#contact").val(ui.item.CONTACTNAME);
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#contact").val(ui.item.PHONENUMBER);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks already try to help. I found the mistake and updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors in your JavaScript:

- "source" is misspelled ("sorGce")
- in availableTags indexes except 0, the colon is inside the quotes instead of outside

Working fiddle:

```
sorGce: availableTags, -> source: availableTags,
"ID:" "23", -> "ID": "23",
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ep1s9w3s/1/

Not sure if this is the root cause of your problem or not, but it might help you fix your fiddle.